# Подключение библиотеки С в С++ и удаление указателя

Tags: c++, c, library, unique-ptr

В С++ коде подключается библиотека, написанная на С. Вызывается функция, которая возвращает указатель `char*`. Можно ли данный указатель обернуть в `std::unique_ptr<char>`? Вопрос с собеседования по С++.

Answer (score 0):

Ну а кто запрещает?

Главное чтобы выделение и освобождение ресурса были организованны верно (new - delete, malloc(calloc) - free), укажите второй параметр шаблона и скормите делитер)

Вот пример с выводом при вызове free

char* AllocChar() - пример функции с интерфейсом С

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

char* AllocChar()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(malloc(sizeof(char)));
}

int main()
{
    auto char_ptr = AllocChar();
    if (!char_ptr) {
        std::cout << "error get pointer" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    auto deleter = [](char* ptr){if (ptr) {
                                     std::cout << "del ptr" << std::endl;
                                     free(ptr);
                                    }
                                };

    std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(deleter)> ptr(char_ptr, deleter);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: что-то форматирование тупит, но тело лямбды вроде должно быть понятно

Comment: Я бы не использовал тяжелую `std::function`, а сначала засунул лямбду в переменную и использовал `decltype(лямбда)` как параметр шаблона.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну это уже дело реализации, суть то ответа в возможности)))) или вы несогласны ?

Comment: Согласен, просто предлагаю небольшое улучшение. :) Еще, кстати, можно `if (ptr)` выкинуть. На нулевом указателе deleter и так не будет вызываться, вроде.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, я поправил, ну у меня нету гарантий что у ТС последняя версии библиотек, но да на nullptr теперь есть проверка)

Comment: Все верно написано, но причем тут  std::unique_ptr<char*>?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan - в смысле? или вы хотите указатель на массив char* если пишите std::unique_ptr<char*> ????

Comment: Beeen007, я ничего не хочу, я вопрос читаю...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Тогда почитайте еще и про unique_ptr

Comment: Мне кажется вопрос был скорее про аллокаторы памяти. Типа указатель должен удаляться тем же аллокатором памяти, что и выделял память, нет ? Типа если библиотека предоставляет аллокатор, умеющий удалять указатель, то наверное можно. Если возвращаемый указатель вообще передаётся во владение клиенту, может быть ведь и просто указателем, и библиотека сама его удалит. Вопрос на поговорить, видимо. А ещё Вы написали `auto ptr = AllocChar()`, это то же самое что `char ptr = AllocChar()`.

Comment: @vegorov вы написали какую-то констатацию фактов которую и все так знают... Какие аллокаторы ? Вопрос про то, можно ли указатель обернуть в умный указатель. Все. Char* и Си понятно что во владение , не const char const *p же.... в конце про auto, это вы вообще не в глаз, а в бровь.....

Comment: В общем, я думал что auto игнорирует cv модификаторы и выводит только тип, то есть `auto a = 2, *b = &other_var;`, а не указатели. Но нет, указатели он тоже выводит, и в варианте `auto ptr = AllocChar()` и в варианте `auto* ptr = AllocChar()` всё работает, видимо потому что типы примитивные, других версий у меня нет. Если бы функция возвращала указатель на пользовательский тип (`struct Foo` какой-нибудь), то сработала бы только запись `auto* foo_ptr = AllocFoo();`, а `auto foo_ptr = AllocFoo();` уже не сработало. Полагаю по этой причине обычно явно пишут `auto* var = ...` или `const auto& ref`